# Totally unexpected output when trying to compute the average using arrays

Tags: arrays, c, function

I am trying to compute the average after reading in the data from a text file of `int` type.The program compiles fine. `clang -std=gnu11 -Weverything -g3 -pedantic -g3 -O3 -lm    average_weight_of_elephant_seals.c   -o average_weight_of_elephant_seals`

Suppose I want to compute the average weight of 2000 seals,the expected output is 6838.848152 but I get 1710.566467.I have no idea how to make sense of GDB yet.

Could someone please point out where have I have gone wrong?

```
/* The following program demonstrates the usage of fscan to read in a set of integer data into a file and then computes the sum followed by the average.
 * The computation shall be encapsulated in a function and then be called in the main routine
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXSIZE 5000 /* Macro definition to pre-define the size of the array */

double average_weight(int count, int weights_array[]);

int main(void)
{
    int number_of_seals;
    int weights_array[MAXSIZE];

    printf("Enter the number of seals: \n");
    scanf("%i", &number_of_seals);

    printf("Their average weight is %lf\n", average_weight(number_of_seals, &weights_array[number_of_seals]));

    return 0;
}

double average_weight(int count, int weights_array[])
{
    /* Variable declaration and initialization
     * Note the use of the FILE data type */
    int weight;
    int sum = 0;
    FILE *elephant_seal_data = fopen("elephant_seal_data.txt", "r");

    if (elephant_seal_data == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    /* FEOF function to determine if EOF has been reached or not */
    while (!feof(elephant_seal_data))
    {
        fscanf(elephant_seal_data, "%i", &weight);
        weights_array[count++] = weight;
        sum += weight;
        count++;
    }

    double average_weight = (double)sum / (double)count;
    fclose(elephant_seal_data);
    return average_weight;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: You are incrementing count twice.

Comment: Please see [Why is "while ( !feof (file) )" always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong?noredirect=1&lq=1).  It's not the main source of your problem (Pete answers that below), but it it is a contributing factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf("Their average weight is %lf\n", average_weight(number_of_seals, &weights_array[number_of_seals]));
```

The code passes a pointer to a position into the array for no apparent reason, and does not check if number_of_seals * 2 is less than MAXSIZE so may overflow the array. But the array isn't needed for this calculation anyway.

```
    weights_array[count++] = weight;
    sum += weight;
    count++;
```

The code is writing to the array not reading it. The array is not needed for this calculation.

The code increments count twice, so the average will be out by a factor of two, and alternate locations in the array will have undefined values in them.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is an assignment and I'm required to use array and pass it to a function.

Comment: @AlokY in that case, you probably want to divide the problem up so one function reads the data from a file into an array then another calculates the average value in that array.

Comment: Alright.I will give that a try.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 stupid mistakes in your code, a nastier one, and a *risk*.

First the stupid ones:

You pass `count` to the function **and** increment that value **twice** per each value in the file. If the initialy given value was correct, you end with a count 3 times too big. You should not pass `count` to the function but *compute* it there.

You use a wrong syntax to pass an array: you are expected to pass a pointer to its first element.

Now the nasty one: while [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/3545273) is indeed a FAQ, is is still a common thing in beginners code...

`feof` only returns true **after** a read operation returned an error. Let us examine what happens for the last value. It is read and correctly processed once. `feof` still returns `false` (no error so far) so your code re-enters the loop. `scanf` reaches the end of file and returns 0 (what your code ignores) but does not change the values => the last value will be processed twice. **Never ever use `while (!feof(...`**

And finally the risk.

You are summing value into an integer. Even if the average will easily fit there, if you had larger value and a very high number of them, you could get an integer overflow. The recommended way it to sum into a larger type (double?) and if possible use a *guess* to limit the cumulative error: average(qty-guess) + guess is indeed average(quantity), but the computed sum can be much lower, limiting the cumulative error when using floating point values or preventing overflow when using integer ones. From the number of seals and the expected average there should be no problem here so a guess is useless, but remember that for a different use case...

Last but not least, `main` is expected to be declared as `int main()` if you do not care for additional parameters but **never** `int main(void)`

Code could become:

```
/* The following program demonstrates the usage of fscan to read in a set of integer data into a file and then computes the sum followed by the average.
 * The computation shall be encapsulated in a function and then be called in the main routine
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXSIZE 5000 /* Macro definition to pre-define the size of the array */

double average_weight(int* count, int weights_array[]);

int main()
{
    int number_of_seals;
    int weights_array[MAXSIZE];

    double weight = average_weight(&number_of_seals, weights_array);
    printf("Their number is %d and their average weight is %lf\n", number_of_seals, weight);

    return 0;
}

double average_weight(int* count, int weights_array[])
{
    /* Variable declaration and initialization
     * Note the use of the FILE data type */
    int weight;
    int sum = 0;
    FILE* elephant_seal_data = fopen("elephant_seal_data.txt", "r");

    if (elephant_seal_data == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    *count = 0;

    /* FEOF function to determine if EOF has been reached or not */
    for(int i=0; i<MAXSIZE; i++) // never process more than the array size
    {
        if (1 != fscanf(elephant_seal_data, "%i", &weight)) {
            break;    // immediately stop at end of file
        }
        weights_array[(* count)++] = weight;
        sum += weight;
    }

    double average_weight = (double)sum / (double)*count;
    fclose(elephant_seal_data);
    return average_weight;
}
```

---

I have kept your general program structure unchanged, but IMHO, you are expected to first read the data into an array, and then pass that populated array along with its count to an average function. Just split your current function into 2 steps.

Comment: When I run the program I get ```Their number is 4199088 and their average weight is -1.000000```

Comment: I have not changed anything to your error processing. Average weight being -1 means that you could not open (find?) the file...

Answer (score 1):

You have sent the number of counts to use in the array which is great, since the function does not know the length of the weights_array. But you are not using it properly.

I'd suggest you to:

- Use `count` to limit the number of loops based on how many data you want.
- Do not change/reassign the value of `count`. Since this number is crucial to calculate the average. Create some other variable to do the task.

So here is how I slightly modified your code to bring those changes. I assumed the format of elephant_seal_data.txt as space separated integer values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXSIZE 5000 /* Macro definition to pre-define the size of the array */

double average_weight(int count, int weights_array[]);

int main(void)
{
    int number_of_seals;
    int weights_array[MAXSIZE];

    printf("Enter the number of seals: \n");
    scanf("%i", &number_of_seals);

    printf("Their average weight is %lf\n", average_weight(number_of_seals, &weights_array[number_of_seals]));

    return 0;
}

double average_weight(int count, int weights_array[])
{
    /* Variable declaration and initialization
     * Note the use of the FILE data type */
    int weight;
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    FILE *elephant_seal_data = fopen("elephant_seal_data.txt", "r");

    if (elephant_seal_data == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    /* FEOF function to determine if EOF has been reached or not */
    while (i<count)
    {
        fscanf(elephant_seal_data, "%d", &weight);
        weights_array[i++] = weight;
        if (feof(elephant_seal_data)) break;
        sum += weight;
    }




    double average_weight = (double)sum / (double)count;
    fclose(elephant_seal_data);
    return average_weight;
}
```

Edit:
I have used the elephant_seals_data.txt to simulate these in Google Colab for you. Try running the first cell [there](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FRkXipPMyMDvTTcRahJejRpJlOfuOf12?usp=sharing).

[Google Colab Link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FRkXipPMyMDvTTcRahJejRpJlOfuOf12?usp=sharing)

Comment: Output: ```Enter the number of seals: 
2000
Their average weight is -1.000000```

Comment: Can you provide the `elephant_seal_data.txt` so that I can check the format and match the answer accordingly?

And I think there is a typo with your file name. Or it is in the wrong directory.

Comment: Sure. https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/W_lzvc89Eem06hL8prFFBA_161b31dd311a49239814cf1dff0bec18_elephant_seal_data?Expires=1641772800&Signature=fJktFqR8MhwcsBPAXhQBfKUldxapgg7IQNZzBTwfBNcMZtsEKFlW7rtkMo82DN8NR0rYRQVx75l4qOTbMNlbi86EQlRs5nY7N4krmMskRd0950tiF8IvBRnWNrOizxv22U8e-Pje5MMf3kXZRvqDzDVJ87ewWCaydyLMwOp8V~M_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A

Comment: I have edited accordingly. Try checking now. Also you may want to try the GoogleColab link to run the code online.

Comment: Awesome! This works.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please consider this if your question is answered. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers